# A gem to describe purpose of gems in gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile

I'm new to RoR and jumping into a big RoR project. The project uses a bunch of gems. In fact, the Gemfile.lock file, including dependencies, is 460 lines long. I was told the project went through several different developers, and that there may be a lot of cruft in there.

Is there any way to generate a list of what each gem does? It's not exactly intuitive, especially with names like "capybara" and "cocaine" and "raindrops."

2. Is there any simple process to determine which gems are required?

Comment: Starting from the `Gemfile` would be easier, and Google search `ruby [gem name]` most likely pointing you to the Github page. I'm sure there are a lot of gems, but I'm not sure there's an easy way to spit out a list of what each Gem does, other than looking up the Gem's rdoc. The environment it's loaded in (`test, dev`) should give you some start of what to expect

Comment: [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=capybara) is also a good resources and gives you a small description of each gem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't stress too much about what's in the `Gemfile.lock` at first, just the `Gemfile`.

To get gem details, I just whipped this little script up to dump summaries of all the gems in your current bundle:

```
require 'yaml'

gems = `bundle list`
names = gems.scan(/^\s+\*\s+([\w-]+)\s+\(.*\)\s*$/).flatten

names.each do |name|
  summary = YAML.parse(`gem spec #{name} summary`).root.value rescue '???'
  puts "#{name}: #{summary}"
end
```

Save it to a file and run it on the command line like so:

`ruby whatever-you-saved-it-as.rb`

For a project of mine, I got this:

```
actionmailer: Email composition, delivery, and receiving framework (part of Rails).
actionpack: Web-flow and rendering framework putting the VC in MVC (part of Rails).
actionview: Rendering framework putting the V in MVC (part of Rails).
activemodel: A toolkit for building modeling frameworks (part of Rails).
activerecord: Object-relational mapper framework (part of Rails).
activesupport: A toolkit of support libraries and Ruby core extensions extracted from the Rails framework.
addressable: URI Implementation
annotate: Annotates Rails Models, routes, fixtures, and others based on the database schema.
arel: Arel is a SQL AST manager for Ruby
ast: A library for working with Abstract Syntax Trees.
astrolabe: An object-oriented AST extension for Parser
awesome_print: Pretty print Ruby objects with proper indentation and colors
...
```

Kinda neat actually.

Comment: @NickVeys Is there a way to limit the output to the contents of the Gemfile, and not **all*** of the dependencies in Gemfile.lock?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that each gem has a meaningful description, you can run something like this from the Rails console:

```rb
Gem.loaded_specs.values.map { |g| "#{g.name}: #{g.summary}" }
```

The dynamic nature of Ruby makes it hard to find unused gems automatically (e.g. through code analysis). However, you can try to remove gems one by one. If your project's test suite passes without a given gem, it is certainly a strong sign that it might be safe to remove it.

Comment: Is there a way to limit the output to the contents of the Gemfile, and not **all*** of the dependencies in Gemfile.lock?